# Why is Raphael.JS creating paper with dimensions 1000x1000?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, raphael

I have a demo using [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/index.html). The code for it is very simple but when viewed in Internet Explorer (less that version 9) I get a Raphael canvas that is 1000px by 1000px and I can't figure out why. I'm using version 1.5.2 of Raphael. Code below:

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Raphael Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <link href="../shared/img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <script src="../shared/js/raphael/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*CSS*

```
/* Graph */
#graph { padding: 5px; width: 477px; height: 299; }
```

*JS*

```
var holder = document.getElementById('graph')
  , width = holder.scrollWidth
  , height = Math.round(width * 0.5625) + 25
  , p = Raphael(10, 50, width, height)
  , c = p.circle(p.width - 50, p.height - 50, 50);
alert(p.width + ' & ' + p.height);
```

I found a discussion in [Raphael's Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/6a888369145a9212/820bbaf1a2ca67f0?lnk=gst&q=internet+explorer#820bbaf1a2ca67f0) with the same problem but no resolution.

Comment: Are you sure you want to access `p.width` (width attribute), and not `p.style.width`?

Comment: Pretty sure. `p.width` should be the width of the drawing surface. `p.style.width` doesn't exist, but `p.canvas.style.width` does (the actual svg element) but has no value. I could use the calculated width and height from before but that doesn't change the size of the canvas and it doesn't make the shape visible.

Comment: I don't know why this example doesn't work but Pumbaa80, your comment helped fix the problem this test case stemmed from, using the calculated height and width things worked much better.

Comment: As mentioned in the IRC channel, you are causing yourself problems by using undocumented features such as p.width and p.height.

Comment: You're absolutely right Adam. I made a (clearly erroneous) assumption about p.width being the equivalent of p.getBBox().width which doesn't even exist. This is what happens when amateurs think they are being clever.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and using

```
var width = paper.canvas.clientWidth ? paper.canvas.clientWidth : paper.width;
var height = paper.canvas.clientHeight ? paper.canvas.clientHeight : paper.height;
```

instead of paper.width and paper.height solved it for ie older than version 9 and all the other browsers.